# backward direction of NAT with "iptables"

Tags: iptables, nat

There are many guides on how to install NAT on Linux with "iptables". They contain a line

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $UPLINK --jump MASQUERADE
```

where `UPLINK` is the name of the network interface connected to the internet. What I don't see is a rule which translates IP packets backwards, namely, translates global IP addresses to local ones. It should look like this.

```
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --in-interface $UPLINK $ARGS
```

Where is backward direction turned on?

Comment: Do you mean DNAT?